# how to define adt constructor for `int list` z3 adt dotnet api

Tags: z3, adt

how to define adt constructor for `int list`

`Context.MkConstructor(name: string, recognizer: string, ?fieldNames: string array, ?sorts: Sort array, ?sortRefs: uint32 array) : Constructor`

The documentation says (`https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#a2a421919ab766bf028ec422723b42e37`)
"**sorts**  field sorts, 0 if the field sort refers to a recursive
**sortRefs**    reference to datatype sort that is an argument to the constructor; if the corresponding sort reference is 0, then the value in sort_refs should be an index referring to one of the recursive datatypes that is declared."

`_.MkConstructor("cons", "is_cons", [|"x"; "y"|], [|_.mkIntSort (); ?1], ?2)`

what should be instead `?`

I tried to set `?1` to `null`, but I can't understand  working principle `sortRefs`,

Comment: The concept is the same as in the Python API; there's a tutorial here: https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/programming/Z3%20Python%20-%20Readonly/advanced#datatypes . A sort is just a "type" , while a sort-ref is a reference to a (recursive) type being declared.

Answer (score 1):

z3 itself comes with an example that does exactly this: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/12e45c9d17aa48151b2c20573fb3b527b32fdb54/examples/dotnet/Program.cs#L1503-L1559

Feel free to ask if you've specific questions, but I suppose the above code is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I had completely forgotten that we .NET examples as well :)